# How to update last accessed with Forms Authentication cookie

Tags: mvc, websites, session, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I've got an MVC 4 site where I'm using Forms Authentication. I'm setting a cookie when a user logs in. The majority of my site does NOT require a user to be logged in though.

What I'd like to do, whenever a user FIRST accesses my site, I'd like to update my "LastLogon" that I have stored in my database table to the corresponding value (if Request.IsAuthenticated). But I don't want it to fire on EVERY page that the user accesses.

So, where do I track when the user first accesses my site? Is that in the Global.asax? Is Application_Start method for all first requests to a site, or is that when the website first loads after an iisreset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized/found yesterday that in the Global.asax that there's a method available called "Session_Start". I believe that will work perfectly.

I could also use the Application_Request method, but I don't want to hit my SQL Server that often.

(I'm also thinking of adding it to the "Session_End" method in case they are on the site for along time...

Here's a link to the Global.asax methods available:

http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.com/2008/03/methods-in-globalasax.html

Edit/Update:

I just stumbled across this article on CodeProject that appears to be the time that the cookie is ready:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/288631/Secure-ASP-NET-MVC-applications